# Plotting (a more complicated) model with three interactions

Tags: r, ggplot2, mixed-models

I want to plot a mixed effect model with three interactions as Jeffrey A. Walker does in his book "Elements of Applied Biostatistics", specifically in [Chapter 4](https://www.middleprofessor.com/files/applied-biostatistics_bookdown/_book/plotting-models.html). He uses the data available [here](https://static-content.springer.com/esm/art%3A10.1038%2Fs41467-020-15483-7/MediaObjects/41467_2020_15483_MOESM4_ESM.xlsx) (it is going to download the data automatically). Then he proceeds the following way:

```
fig2e_wide <- read_excel("41467_2020_15483_MOESM4_ESM.xlsx",
                     sheet = "Source Date_Figure 2",
                     range = c("A233:O236"), # lot of NA
                     col_names = FALSE) %>%
  data.table %>%
  transpose(make.names = 1) # turn data onto 

# melt the four columns into a single "glucose_auc" column
# and create a new column containing treatment level.
y_cols <- colnames(fig2e_wide)

# melt
fig2e <- melt(fig2e_wide,
               measure.vars = y_cols,
               value.name = "glucose_auc",
               variable.name = "treatment")

# create two new columns that are the split of treatment
fig2e[, c("ask1", "diet") := tstrsplit(treatment,
                                        " ",
                                        fixed=TRUE)]

# since glucose_auc is the only response variable in this
# data.table, omit all rows with any NA
fig2e <- na.omit(fig2e)
# View(fig2e)
```

He fits the model:

```
m1 <- lm(glucose_auc ~ ask1*diet,
               data = fig2e)
```

Then he computes the modeled means table of estimated means and confidence intervals (1) and the contrasts table of estimated effects with confidence intervals and p-values:

```
# (1)
m1_emm <- emmeans(m1, specs = c("ask1", "diet"))
m1_emm

# (2)

m1_simple <- contrast(m1_emm,
                     method = "revpairwise",
                     simple = "each",
                     combine = TRUE,
                     adjust = "none") %>%
  summary(infer = TRUE)
m1_simple
```

Then he uses [this amazing code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/middleprofessor/applied-biostats/master/R/ggplot_the_model.R), "ggplot_the_model.R" to create the following graphs with ggplot_the_model:

```
m1_plot <- ggplot_the_model(
  fit = m1,
  fit_emm = m1_emm,
  fit_pairs = m1_simple,
  palette = pal_okabe_ito_blue,
  y_label = expression(paste("mmol ", l^-1, " min")),
  g_label = "none",
  effect_label = expression(paste("Effect (mmol ", l^-1, " min)"))
)

m1_plot
```

m1_plot looks like this:

[image]

I've been trying to modify "ggplot_the_model.R" for at least two weeks so I can plot a three interaction model. In the plot showed above you can see that it does not have a problem with two interactions but with three, i.e., variable1xvariable2xvariable3 yes.

I would appreciate any kind of help!

Comment: hi paula. This question is really difficult to answer in its current form. a few issues: 1) instead of making us download an excel sheet just for a few rows of data, could you post the data here directly? (you probably know `dput(...)`. This is also better for posterity. 2) The question seems to be, how to modify the underlying function. This requires to go through a lot (!!!) of code, to which you have linked. This is quite a lot to go through and really really not easy. It would be good if you could show us what specifically you have tried to modify and where you think it is stuck.

Comment: Then, ideally focus the question to that problem. 3) What do you exactly have in mind when you say "interaction between three variables", and how do you want the plot to look like? We will need this information in order to better help you